# system error - PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: database

I am having problems accessing my modules. The system keeps displaying the following message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'jasmine_ah.field_config' doesn't exist: SELECT fc.* FROM
>   {field_config} fc WHERE (module = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND
>   (fc.active = :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (fc.storage_active =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_2) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0]
>   => taxonomy [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 1 ) in field_read_fields() (line 349
>   of /Users/jasmine/Sites/Drupal/modules/field/field.crud.inc). The
>   website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Do you have any suggestions as to how I can go about resolving this problem? I am using Drupal 7.9 and the Zen theme.

Comment: Have you recently restored you database from a backup ? This error shows that Field module is activated but doesn't find its `field_config` table.

Comment: hi, yes the error started showing up after i restored my database from my back up. Is it possible to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried restoring it again ? It seems that your backup has restored incompletely.

Comment: thanks, i have tried restoring it again, but still getting the same message :(

Comment: I'm having this issue too. This is obviously a very old question, but therefor maybe someone might know how to work around it by now?